# javascript datetime regExp

Tags: javascript, regex, datetime, datetimepicker

Calling Experts on regular expressions .
Need to validate 2017-12-25 12:15:11 format.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please elaborate how you expect single digits days, months, hour, minute, and seconds are to be represented (e.g. 1 or 01), and clarify that time is in 24-hour format (I assume).

Comment: Additionally, if you need to parse/validate datetime strings, take a look at the http://momentjs.com library for a robust and well tested/adopted solution.

Comment: @arash  yy-dd-mm hh:mm:ss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let expression = /\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/;
console.log(expression.test('2017-12-25 12:15:11'));
```

learn more about regular expression in JS 
[Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: It's obviously an incorrect answer:
`console.log(expression.test('2017-99-99 12:15:11'));` => true

Comment: Yes I understand that  but what  I do here is just the shape of the format not validate it and that's can with other utilities

Answer (score 1):

It will be very hard to build a good date time string validator with a regex. You would have to consider the fact that different months have different number of days. Leap years make it even more complicated.

Why not use the `new Date('date string to validate')`?

```
`new Date("2017-12-22 12:15:11")` // Fri Dec 22 2017 12:15:11 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)

`new Date("2017-12-32 12:15:11")` // Invalid Date
```

Or use some more powerful date engines like [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

```
var myDate = moment('2017-12-31 12:15:13', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss').isValid();
console.log(myDate) // true

var myDate = moment('2017-12-33 12:15:13', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss').isValid();
console.log(myDate) // false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/^\d{4}([-/ ])\d{2}\1\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$/
/^\d{4}([-/ ])\d{2}\1\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$/.test("2017-12-25 12:15:11")  //copy to chrome console test true or false
```

Comment: Could you please explain your answer so it’s not a code only answer